# Recursive data structure with variant

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In C++17, is it possible to declare something like this such that it compiles:

```
struct Foo;

using Var = std::variant<Type1, Type2, Foo>; // uses Foo

struct Foo {
    std::vector<Var> member; // uses Var
}
```

This is a simplified example, but I need a recursive data structure like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. All you need is some sort of indirection/container that works properly with *incomplete types*. Examples are: `std::unique_ptr`, `std::vector`, and `std::map`.

```
struct Foo
{
    std::variant<int, float, std::vector<Foo>> _data;
};

int main()
{
    Foo a{std::vector<Foo>{Foo{}, Foo{}}};
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/R340Ga2nmWlYserR)

---

Indirection is required in order to avoid defining an "infinite size" variant. Here are some learning resources on the topic:

- David Sankel's [**“Variants: Past, Present, and Future"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3O4EKX4z1c) CppCon 2016 talk is a great introduction to variants in general and covers *"recursive variants"*.
- I briefly cover *"recursive variants"* in my [**"visiting variants using lambdas pt.2"**](http://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/variants_lambdas_part_2.html) article.